# list' object has no attribute 'split

Tags: function, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, stop-words, data-preprocessing

as I understand I am trying to split the text i.e. input that we will get not the list, where am I going wrong?

While running the below code I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

```py
def remove_stopwords(text):
  x=[]
  for i in text.split():
  # checking if the splitted word is in above imported stopwords list, if  not, we are appending the word in an empty list
    if i not in stopwords.words('english'):
      x.append(i)
  # copying the content of x to y before clearing x and making iit ready for next iteration
  y=x[:]
  x.clear()
  return y
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include how you are using ```remove_stopwords()```.  Apparently you are passing a ```list```  to it.

Answer (score 0):

the text variable you are providing to the function is of a type `list` instead of `str`. Either your text is a list of texts and you want to do splitting for each text. then you need to loop over each one and call the function.

```py
list_of_textx = [remove_stopwords (text) for text in texts]
```

Or you want to call this line prior to call your function

```py
text = ''.join(text)
```